# Define a method to call when event occurs in module

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I can only find answers for different questions.

This gist of what I'm trying to do is I have a module that calls a function in another module when a user clicks clicks on a button. But this is very tightly coupled and leads to various maintenance problems where changing code in one module means I have to change it in multiple other modules.

What I'd like to do instead is just to define a function or property that is then called after the user clicks on a button.

Current code example:

```
// MyModule.js
class MyClass() {
    constructor(options) {
        // Set options
        // ...
    }

    // Called when button is clicked via event listener
    onClick() {
        // Update Module State
        // ...

        AnotherModule.someFunction(clickInfo);
    }
}
```

But this is not flexible at all, and means the modules cannot exist separately.

I'd prefer to having something like this:

```
// MyModule.js
class MyClass() {
    constructor(options) {
        // Set options
        // ...

        this.clickCallback = null; // Function to be called
    }

    // Called when button is clicked via event listener
    onClick() {
        // Update Module State
        // ...

        this.onClickCallback(clickInfo);
    }

    // Called everytime user clicks
    onClickCallback(clickInfo) {
        this.clickCallback(clickInfo);
    }

    setClickCallback(customFunction) {
        this.clickCallback = customFunction;
    }
}

// SomeOtherFile.js
import myModule from './mymodule'

myModule.setClickCallback( (clickInfo) => { this.myFunction(clickInfo) } );

myFunction(data) {
    // Do stuff with click data
}
```

But this means I can only have 1 external function defined. What if I needed to have multiple functions called after clickInfo is calculated?
Is this the correct idea at the least?
Should I be setting the `clickCallback` function through a method or by setting the property?
Should I be using some type of custom event emitter/listener instead?

I thought about using a callback directly, but it doesn't make sense to use a callback because I want the function to be called multiple times.

(In case it isn't clear by the `class` keyword, I am using ES6 and Babel).

Edit: Seems like the better approach would be to add a function to an array when the `onClickCallback()` function is called, and then create a dispatch function that loops through that array calling all the functions with the data passed as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a callback is supposed to be reused, it can be passed on construction:

```
class MyClass() {
    constructor(options) {
        // Set options
        // ...

        this.clickCallback = options.clickHandler;
    }
    ...
}
```

Setting properties from constructor parameters or single options object is applicable in any case where instance property can be set.

> But this means I can only have 1 external function defined. What if I needed to have multiple functions called after clickInfo is calculated?

Then multiple functions can be called:

```
new MyClass({
  clickHandler: clickInfo => {
    this.foo(clickInfo);
    this.bar(clickInfo);
  }
});
```

Comment: How about using an array instead of an object to hold them? Easier to iterate over an array. If so, then does it make sense to also provide a function for defining additional callback functions after instantiation? Doing a quick test this seems to work, but wasn't sure if it's 'correct'.

Comment: Just realized that was a lambda function and not an object, but the question about defining additional callbacks remains.

Comment: I'd say that this is a subject for KISS principle. If you're not sure why it's beneficial, don't do it. You will need to bind each callback in an array, while a single arrow call calls them with proper context. If you feel that you need more control over callbacks, you can use some pub-sub library/event emitter implementation. E.g. RxJS can act as general purpose event emitter.

Comment: Yea, I think you've got a good point there. Think I might have fallen victim to a bit of analysis paralysis on this right now so might as well just KISS until I need more. And I'm using Vue.js w/Vuex so I have a few options for pub-sub, but wanted to keep these modules as standalone as possible. Thanks for the advice. Helps to just try and talk these things out sometimes.